# Wiriting a typecast function for a class which cannot be modified

Tags: c++, casting, type-conversion, static-cast

I have a particular class for which I want to write a typecast operator, but I can't modify the class code directly.

Example:

```
class MyClass; // not modifyable

class MyClass
{
    // can't do this
    operator AnotherType () const
    {
        AnotherType t;
        t.setSomething();
        return t;
    }
}

MyClass m;
static_cast<AnotherType> m; // want to be able to do this
```

Is it possible to express as an external function something which will be called by `static_cast`?

This was my attempt, which did not work, and I did not expect to work.

```
operator AnotherType(MyClass m)
{
    AnotherType t;
    t.setSomething();
    return t;
}
```

The error produced by the compiler indicates that `static_cast` is looking for a constructor for `AnotherType` which takes a `MyClass` as an argument. This indicates a possible alternative, which would be to write a conversion constructor. This will only work if the type to be cast to is modifyable.

It would also be possible to write an external function which does the conversion without the use of a conversion constructor. But this will not be called by `static_cast`.

eg:

```
AnotherType convertFunction(MyClass) {...}
```

There is an alternative solution which it to use the Adapter pattern, and write a type-conversion operator in the Adapter class. It might be this is the only solution in my case.

Comment: why does it have to be a `static_cast` ? Whats wrong with `convertFunction`?

Answer (score 0):

You can't have `A a; static_cast<B>(a);` work if you can't change `A` nor `B`.

You can have `A a; B b = static_cast<Something>(a);` work, if you can define `Something`.

[See it on coliru](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b9be3b83fce121b6)